# Postgres jsonpath ANY Equivalent

Tags: postgresql

Consider the following json:

```
{
  "floor": [
    {
      "level": 1,
      "apt": [
        {
          "no": 1,
          "area": 40,
          "rooms": 1
        },
        {
          "no": 2,
          "area": 80,
          "rooms": 3
        },
        {
          "no": 3,
          "area": null,
          "rooms": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "level": 2,
      "apt": [
        {
          "no": 4,
          "area": 100,
          "rooms": 3
        },
        {
          "no": 5,
          "area": 60,
          "rooms": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Using Postgres jsonpath, if I wanted to get the apartments with 3 rooms, the following would suffice:

```
'$.floor[*].apt[*] ? (@.rooms == 3)'
```

My question is how would I do the same if I wanted to compared against an ARRAY such that I could provide the number of rooms in an array similar to ANY in SQL

```
'$.floor[*].apt[*] ? (@.rooms = ANY{3,5,6,10,11} )'
```

Using Postgres 12.2 on Linux Ubuntu 18.04, 64Bit

Comment: I assume using an or is not an option? e.g. `(@.rooms = 3 || @.rooms == 5 || .. )`

Comment: Not an option :-)

Creating that on the fly not trivial and they could be many variables > 10

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do that with jsonpath.

I'd *suggest* pulling apartments with *any number* of rooms and filtering *that* list, but I suspect that would get quite large as the dataset grows ...

... but then, if you're talking about *large* data volumes here, I would have to ask *why* you're not doing this is a proper, Relational way?  Yes, you *can* get postgres to do this with JSON data but *should you*?  This is a very simple data structure that you could represent in a *single table* which, properly indexed, will cope with huge data volumes.

```
select level, no, size, rooms 
from apts
order by 1, 2 ; 

+-------+----+------+-------+
| level | no | size | rooms |
+-------+----+------+-------+
|     1 |  1 |   40 |     1 |
|     1 |  2 |   80 |     3 |
|     1 |  3 | null |     2 | 
|     2 |  4 |  100 |     3 |
|     2 |  4 |   60 |     2 |
+-------+----+------+-------+

select * 
from apts 
where rooms in ( 3, 5, 6, 10, 11 ) ; 

+-------+----+------+-------+
| level | no | size | rooms |
+-------+----+------+-------+
|     1 |  2 |   80 |     3 |
|     2 |  4 |  100 |     3 |
+-------+----+------+-------+
```

Relational databases are *really good* at finding small bits of [related] data and bolting them back together again.  They're generally pretty *rubbish* at taking large blocks of data, like chunks of JSON, and pulling them apart again.  Yes, RDBMS providers are *trying* to improve this, but I would suggest it'll still be *way* slower than doing it the "old-fashioned" way.

Comment: We just prefer to use jsonb a lot. 

It does simplify things for us by a huge margin seeing it has indexes just as normal tables have in postgres while mapping very easily to our application layer.

There is already a solution using lateral join that works, but jsonpath is neater...

Hope to get some pointers...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like given below:

```
SELECT
    apt
FROM (
    SELECT
        jsonb_path_query(data, '$.floor[*].apt[*]') AS apt
    FROM
        json_test) foo
WHERE
    apt ->> 'rooms' = ANY (ARRAY[3, 4, 5]);
```

Comment: This should work, but

1. Has a subquery, so I assume would take a performance hit... I will have to test.

2. Uses the normal jsonb operators (->>) so we are back to something similar to lateral joins

Any ideas on a pure jsonpath query?